# Laravel Resumable Download

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, download

My PHP script is downloading a zip file to the user using Laravel's **Response::download** function :

```
$file    = public_path(). "/storage/rhcloud/lobby/0.1.zip";
$downloadName = "lobby-0.1";
$headers = array(
   'Content-Type: application/zip',
);
return Response::download($file, $downloadName, $headers);
```

The download works correctly. But, can't do the pause/resume download function.

I have searched all over the web, but didn't find anything. Does Laravel support this partial content downloading or should native PHP code should be used instead of Laravel's ?

Even if I add additional code, how can I make **Response::download** function to fetch data from the given bytes from user request header ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify the content-length (i.e. size of the file) the browser doesn't know how or where to resume the download from. Also, you can use `basename()` function to grab the file name from full path - no need to hard code it

Try this:

```
$file    = public_path(). "/storage/rhcloud/lobby/0.1.zip";
$headers = [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
   'Content-Length' => filesize($file)
];
return Response::download($file, basename($file), $headers);
```

Or for older Laravel versions, like OP's, try:

```
$file    = public_path(). "/storage/rhcloud/lobby/0.1.zip";
$headers = array(
   'Content-Type: application/zip',
   'Content-Length: '. filesize($file)
);
return Response::download($file, basename($file), $headers);
```